# instanciate a fragment with a new class name

Tags: android, android-fragments

i want to change my fragment (Fragment1) class source name, when i click on a button in another fragment (Fragment2).
I add this line in Fragment2:

```
Fragment1.instantiate(getParent(), "com.infrabel.railtime.fragments.MyTitleFragment");
```

But it doesn't change the inside of Fragment1!!

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that fragments are set up to do what you are trying to do here.  It seems like what you really want is to perform a fragment transaction, removing fragment1 and adding in 'fragment3' which is MyTitleFragment, like what is demo'd in this example from the [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) documentation:

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```